# How to account for solvation of a molecule explicitly in quantum calculation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I'm looking for a way to account for hydrogen bonds formed with my molecule in aqueous solution explicitly in DFT calculation. I'll do it in order to compare stability of two structures in water. As far as I understand, it can be done by molecular dynamics calculation of the structure surrounded by molecules of water or by multiple random choice of H2O molecules around the structure with subsequent optimization.

Any suggestions, references to articles or programs are appreciated.

Comment: There are several approaches, with different computational cost and different scope. Can you tell more about your project? For example, which molecules (or types of molecules) are involved? Knowing this information could guide you towards an appropriate force field, if needed. It also helps to understand if your problem is a complex "conformational" problem, or if it can be solved "easily" with QM or QM/MM methods. Also, what do you want to calculate? Is it a problem about energy, geometry, or what else?

Comment: Thank you for reply! It's a problem about energy. It involves equilibrium between ketone and organic peroxide generated by nucleophilic addition of H2O2 dissolved in water to this ketone. The molecule of ketone has only C=O groups and corresponding peroxide has only C-O-C and C-O-O-C groups. I need to figure out the direction in which this equilibrium is shifted.

Comment: Do you _need_ explicit water? If the molecule doesn't have intramolecular hydrogen bonding (eg. in sugars), implicit solvent models are quite good for calculating geometries and energies in solution. The typical process involves calculation in the gas phase, and later refinement with any implicit model (COSMO, SMD, PCM, etc...).

Comment: I believe I do. If I use only implicit model SMD the energy difference is not realistic. If I add in the system one H2O molecule on every lone pair of oxygen to simulate hydrogen bonds the results start to make sense. So I want to use something more reliable to make sure that the result I get are right. 
By the way, my ketone is enolizable so this might be the reason why only implicit SMD don't perform too well.

Comment: A paper I referred to in the past is this: https://doi.org/10.1002/jlac.1995199511272 If you really wanted a precise result, you could set up a molecular dynamics simulation if the species are supported by a force field. By analyzing the geometries, if hydrogen bonding matters you will find water molecules in "specific" positions. Then you could find the average or the most representative geometry, and from that point manually include the right water molecules and go on with QM calculations (sometimes, combining implicit models and explicit water works wonderfully here)

Comment: I don't think adding explicit water molecules is a good idea, though, because it poses several questions that is hard to answer, for example how many molecules do you need? One, two, three...? I remember reading (sorry I don't have a reference for it, though :/ ) that you need at least 18 water molecules to have a realistic account. I would go back to only using an implicit solvation model, mostly if you are not an expert. What kind of functional/basis set are you using? It is possible that the "unrealistic energies" that you are talking about depend on the level of theory.